# stop_gradient in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-gradient

I am wondering if tf.stop_gradient stops the gradient computation of just a given op, or stops the update of its input tf.variable ? I have the following problem - During the forward path computation in MNIST, I would like to perform a set of operations on the weights (let's say W to W*) and then do a matmul with inputs. However, I would like to exclude these operations from the backward path. I want only dE/dW computed during training with back propagation. The code I wrote prevents W from getting updated. Could you please help me understand why ? If these were variables, I understand I should set their trainable property to false, but these are operations on weights. If stop_gradient cannot be used for this purpose, then how do I build two graphs, one for forward path and the other for back propagation ?

```
def build_layer(inputs, fmap, nscope,layer_size1,layer_size2, faulty_training):  
  with tf.name_scope(nscope): 
    if (faulty_training):
      ## trainable weight
      weights_i = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([layer_size1, layer_size2],stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(float(layer_size1))),name='weights_i')
      ## Operations on weight whose gradient should not be computed during backpropagation
      weights_fx_t = tf.multiply(268435456.0,weights_i)
      weight_fx_t = tf.stop_gradient(weights_fx_t)
      weights_fx = tf.cast(weights_fx_t,tf.int32)
      weight_fx = tf.stop_gradient(weights_fx)
      weights_fx_fault = tf.bitwise.bitwise_xor(weights_fx,fmap)
      weight_fx_fault = tf.stop_gradient(weights_fx_fault)
      weights_fl = tf.cast(weights_fx_fault, tf.float32)
      weight_fl = tf.stop_gradient(weights_fl)
      weights = tf.stop_gradient(tf.multiply((1.0/268435456.0),weights_fl))
      ##### end transformation
    else:
      weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([layer_size1, layer_size2],stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(float(layer_size1))),name='weights')


    biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([layer_size2]), name='biases')
    hidden = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(inputs, weights) + biases)
    return weights,hidden
```

I am using the tensorflow gradient descent optimizer to do the training.

```
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate) 
global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step', trainable=False) 
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)
```

Answer (score 2):

Stop gradient will prevent the backpropagation from continuing past that node in the graph. You code doesn't have any path from weights_i to the loss except the one that goes through weights_fx_t where the gradient is stopped. This is what is causing weights_i not to be updated during training. You don't need to put stop_gradient after every step. Using it just once will stop the backpropagation there.

If `stop_gradient` doesn't do what you want then you can get the gradients by doing `tf.gradients` and you can write your own update op by using `tf.assign`. This will allow you to alter the gradients however you want.

Comment: Ah.. I see. That stop_gradient will prevent backpropagation from continuing past that node wasn't obvious to me from the documentation. Thanks for clarifying. I guess I'll just try altering the gradients then.